# How is it possible to properly close an app?

Tags: android, exit

I'm stuck exiting my android app. In my app I have a main activity that is called first and a user menu that is started like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMainpage.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

I created an event listener within the UserMainpage to find out if the back button was pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(backcounter >= 1){
        *code to close app*
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.EXIT_APPLICATION), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        backcounter++;
    }
}
```

The first time it's pressed a user gets a toast, the second time it should exit the app. I was able to close the app, but when I press the square button I can see that the app is still started. Any ideas how to quit the app completely?

I already tried these different suggestions, but they didn't work:

```
finish();
finishAffinity();
finishAndRemoveTask();
System.exit(0);
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

as well as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```

in the main activity.

It is not possible to use the default back button functionality because the main activity will automatically forward to either a login page or the user menu.

Comment: You mean to say that you are able to see the app when you hit the "recent apps" button and you dont wanna see your app there?

Comment: you can't *quit app completely* (remove from recent apps), as it is managed by the system. You should not bother about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first time it's pressed a user gets a toast, the second time it
>   should exit the app. I was able to close the app, but when I press the
>   square button I can see that the app is still started. Any ideas how
>   to quit the app completely?

That is not possible on Android. All you can do is calling `finish();`. Mostly your app will be still shown in the running apps menu but it is not running at all. So don't worry about this. If your app closes when calling `finish()`, you are just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that, was just afraid that it would drain the users batteries. Thanks :)